# Unable to start the Java Configuration

Tags: java, eclipse

I am unable to run the configuration from my rational software. I really do not want to re-install it. If anyone has face any issue please let me know how to resolve it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use x86 (32 bit) Eclipse.
That should solve the problem...